# Temperature Conversion Script - php issue

Tags: php, if-statement, syntax, syntax-error, temperature

I'm trying to figure out a way to convert celsius to fahrenheit using php. Here's my code so far. It keeps saying I have a unexpected '{' on line 12.

```
<html>
<body>
<?php
    for ($num=10, $num1=$num, $max=100; $num <= $max; $num++)
{
    if ((($num % 10) == 0))
{
    echo $num;
    echo ( " converted to fahrenheit is " );
}
    elseif ((5/9) * ($num1 - 32)
{
    echo $num1;
    echo ( "</br>" );
}
}
echo ( "</br> End Loop." );
?>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm a beginner. Just trying to get a grasp on php. Any help will be appreciated.

EDIT: It's supposed to convert every number divisble by 10 (e.g. 10, 20, 30, 40...) from Celsius to Fahrenheit.

Comment: Please indent your code; this is really hard to read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The specific error you're getting is because this:

```
elseif ((5/9) * ($num1 - 32)
```

Needs to be:

```
elseif ((5/9) * ($num1 - 32))
```

(Missing closing paren)

I think your entire script could be rewritten like this:

```
for ($num=10; $num <= 100; $num += 10) {
    $f = (($num * 9) / 5) + 32;
    echo "$num converted to fahrenheit is $f</br>";
}
```

Working example: http://3v4l.org/iT7p0

Comment: I forgot to include that I need to convert every 10th number (10,20,30...) from Celsius to Fahrenheit. Would I still need a for loop for that?

Comment: Well sure a loop would be useful for that part. Did my answer solve your specific question above though about the `unexpected '{'`?

Comment: Yes sir. Thanks! Right now, I'm dealing with this. http://i.imgur.com/xmZTO8E.png

Comment: Is there a way I could combine my if and else if statements into one if statement?

Comment: holy smokes! thanks so much! i didn't know you could do that in the for statement.